# Asset Pipeline not including CSS or JS in Grails 3 on external Tomcat 7/8

Tags: grails, tomcat7, asset-pipeline, grails3.2.0

When I upload the app.war.original from a 3.2.8 app to a tomcat7 or tomcat8 running on a java 1.8.0_51 server, assets are not included in my source, as if the asset:stylesheet and asset:javascript tags didn't exist in my layout.

The app is running fine with :

```
java -D"grails.env"=prod -jar .\build\libs\app-x.y.z.war
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was quartz-monitor plugin pulling an old version of asset-pipeline in my war file.